# can anybody please give me an example of SELECT with CASE statement

Tags: mysql, select, case

i have table named `chat_users` with columns:

### id | username | status | time_mod | views

Here is an example of UPDATE with CASE statement that works brilliantly:

```
$db->exec("UPDATE `proba13`.`chat_users`
SET `username` = CASE id
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Jie'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Mie'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Pres'
END,
`status` = CASE id
    WHEN 4 THEN '1'
    WHEN 5 THEN '2'
    WHEN 6 THEN '3'
END
WHERE id IN (4,5,6)");
```

QUESTION:
can anybody please give me an example of SELECT with CASE statement on the same table ?

regards and
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This will return the same results as your updated table (however, obviously without making any changes to it):

```
SELECT id,
       CASE id
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Jie'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Mie'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Pres'
         ELSE username
       END AS username,
       CASE id
         WHEN 4 THEN 1
         WHEN 5 THEN 2
         WHEN 6 THEN 3
         ELSE status
       END AS status,
       time_mod,
       views
FROM   proba13.chat_users
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT  (CASE WHEN 
    id =4 THEN 'Jie'
    WHEN id =5 THEN 'Mie'
    WHEN id =6 THEN 'Pres'
END ) `username` ,
 (CASE  WHEN 
   id= 4 THEN '1'
    WHEN  id= 5 THEN '2'
    WHEN  id= 6 THEN '3'
END ) `status`  FROM  `chat_users` 
WHERE id IN (4,5,6)
```